# align text fields to right html form css

Tags: css, forms, html, alignment

I am trying to align a form's text fields to the right side of the div in which they are contained. I have this for css:

application.css

```
#loginform {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgba(237,191,92, 1);
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#usertext, #passtext {
    text-align: left;
}

#loginuser, #loginpass {
    text-align: right;
}

#submitbutton {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is my html:

indexform.php

```
<div id="loginform">
<form id="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <h1>Member Login</h1>
    <div id="usertext">
        <p>Username:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="passtext">
        <p>Password:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="loginuser">
        <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername">
    </div>
    <div id="loginpass">
        <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword">
    </div>
    <div id="submitbutton">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

What happens now:

```
Username:
Password:

|--username textfield--|
|--password textfield--|

|-login button-|
```

The text fields should be lined up to the right of the "Username:" and "Password:" labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DyxZF/)

```
 <div id="loginuser">
    <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername">
</div>
<div id="usertext">
    <p>Username:</p>
</div>
<div id="loginpass">
    <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword">
</div>
<div id="passtext">
    <p>Password:</p>
</div>
```

and

```
#loginuser, #loginpass {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: You should also indicate the changes you made to the mark up.